# Does the property $\min_{c \in \mathbb{R}} E[ (X-c)^2] =E[ (X-E[X])^2]$ generalize to the covariance of $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

It is well known that 
\begin{align}
\min_{c \in \mathbb{R}} E[ (X-c)^2] =E[ (X-E[X])^2]= V(X)
\end{align}

My question does this property in some nontrivial way (I don't know which way) generalize to the covariance.  Where the covariance for a pair $(X,Y)$ is defined as
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y)=E[(X-E[X]) (Y-E[Y])  ]. 
\end{align}

Comment: so you mean 
\begin{align}
\min_{(c_x,c_y) \in \mathbb{R}^2} E[(X-c_x) (Y-c_y)  ]
\end{align}
?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi  No. Obviously, this will lead to - infinitiy.

Comment: @Boby You could have mentioned in your question that you know that this is not the way to go...

Comment: @saz  Sorry, I should have.

Comment: @Boby Nothing prevents you from still editing the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$E[(X-a)^2] = \sigma_X^2 + (\mu_X-a)^2$$  where $\mu_X:=E[X]$ and $\sigma_X:=\sqrt{E[(X-\mu_X)^2]}$. So, $a=\mu_X$ is minimizes $f(a) = E[(X-a)^2].$

The "generalization" of this equation is

$$E[(X-a)(Y-b)] = Cov(X,Y) + (\mu_X-a)(\mu_Y-b).$$

So, $(a,b)=(\mu_X, \mu_Y)$ is the saddle-point of the hyperbolic-paraboloid $z=g(a,b)=E[(X-a)(Y-b)]$.

Answer (score 1):

It might be tempting to think that $$\text{cov}(X,Y) = \min_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}((X-a)(Y-b)).$$ This is, however, not true. It's easy to see that "$\geq$" always holds (take $a=\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $b=\mathbb{E}(Y)$) but "$\leq$" is, in general, wrong.

Consider for instance two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Then

$$\text{cov}(X,Y)=  \mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}(X)) \mathbb{E}(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)=0.$$

However,

$$\min_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}((X-a)(Y-b)) = \min_{a,b} (\mathbb{E}(X)-a) (\mathbb{E}(Y)-b) =- \infty$$

(choose $a=\mathbb{E}(X)+n^2$ and $b=\mathbb{E}(Y)-1/n$).

---

This being said, I'm not sure whether there is some other way to generalize the variation principle to the covariance.

Comment: @Boby, obviously yes, this is what this answer addresses :)